# How can I check if a file with given name exists in same directory?

Tags: bash

Given a filename (the presented as full name, namely, the path to the file from the current folder), how can I check if exists there (in the folder of the file "filename") , file with name `f`?

Comment: Clarifying: given "/home/whatever/name.txt", you want to know whether "name.txt" exists in the current directory ?

Comment: You have to be more specific than this, what language are you using? in which environment?

Comment: @AlyShmahell It's tagged bash, so I assume bash.

Comment: @AlyShmahell he tagged bash in the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I had't noticed at the time.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is, given "/long/path/name.txt", determine whether a file named "name.txt" exists in the current directory, then:

```
LONG=/long/path/name.txt
SHORT=${LONG##*/}
if [ -f "$SHORT" ]; then
    echo file exists
else
    echo file does not exist
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ -e $(dirname "${startname}")/"f" ]]; then
echo "exists"
fi
```

to check that `f` exists in the same directory as `${startname}` is.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to check for the existence of file "f" knowing the path to a neighbor file.
Here is a bash shell-script (let's call it "findNeighborFile.sh") that does the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

neighbor=$1
target=$2
directory=$(dirname "${neighbor}")
if [ -f "$neighbor" ]; then
    echo "$neighbor is present"
    if [ -f "$directory/$target" ]; then
        echo "$directory/$target is present"
    else
        echo "$directory/$target is not present"
    fi
else
    echo "$neighbor is not present"
    if [ -f "$directory/$target" ]; then
        echo "$directory/$target is present"
    else
        echo "$directory/$target is not present"
    fi
fi
```

The script takes in two arguments: first the neighbor file path, second the target file you're looking for.
Let's say you have a directory called "test" located in the same directory as the script, and "test" contains two files "f1", "f2". now you can try different test-cases:

Both files exist:

```
./findNeighborFile.sh ./test/f1 f2
./test/f1 is present
./test/f2 is present
```

Target does not exist:

```
./findNeighborFile.sh ./test/f1 f3
./test/f1 is present
./test/f3 is not present
```

Neighbor does not exist:

```
./test/f3 is not present
./test/f2 is present
```

Neither file exists:

```
./findNeighborFile.sh ./test/f3 f4
./test/f3 is not present
./test/f4 is not present
```